# Can't update a mongo value with a dynamic array id from a meteor form

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got a meteor event in which I'm trying to update one value in a number of sub documents from an event handler.

The string I'm putting together is order.0.number, order.1.number etc.. and I can see the correct strings being generated in the debugger. I can also manually update the field in the console, but the code stubbonly refuses to update the numbers.

The event code is

```
   'click #closeEdit': function(evt,tmpl) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Session.set('showEditEvent',false);
    Session.set('lastMod', new Date());
    Requests.update({_id:Session.get('editingReqEvent')}, {$set: {locked_by: null}});

   var request = Requests.findOne({_id:Session.get('editingReqEvent')});
    for (i=1; i <= request.order.length; i++) {
      var val=tmpl.find('#'+i).value;
      if(!val) {// its null
        val = 0
      }
      var toSet = "order."+(i-1)+".number";
      debugger;
      Requests.update({_id:Session.get('editingReqEvent')}, {$set: {toSet: parseInt(val)}});
    }
  },
```

Any ideas how I should be doing this (obviously what I have here isn't the way to do it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{toSet: parseInt(val)}` will create an object with the key `toSet`. Not what you want, right? You need to do something like:

```
var toSet = "order."+(i-1)+".number"
var updates = {}
updates[toSet] = parseInt(val)
Requests.update(Session.get('editingReqEvent'), {$set: updates})
```

PS, in your code, create `i` as a local variable instead of a global variable (guessing you're not using it as a global variable). DS

Answer (score 1):

```
{toSet: parseInt(val)}
```

In this code `toSet` won't evaluate to `order.x.number` as it is a key. The update query will try to set the value of the `toSet` property in document. You can get around this issue with a code like this:

```
var toSet = {};
var toSet["order."+(i-1)+".number"] = parseInt(val);
Requests.update({_id:Session.get('editingReqEvent')}, {$set: toSet});
```